# Android/Java sensor hashCode() giving different values in distinct activity/service

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-sensors, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have an application using sensors listeners. Basically, I have a main activity with something like this:

**MainActivity.java**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
   (...)
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Accelerometer hashCode MA: " + mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).hashCode());
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Accelerometer reference MA: " + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER))));
   }
}
```

And I have a Service started from the MainActivity like this:

```
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SensorService.class));
```

My service class is:

**SensorService.java**

```
public class SensorService extends Service implements SensorEventListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener
{
   private SensorManager mSensorManager;
   (...)
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
   {
      mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Accelerometer hashCode SS: " + mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).hashCode());
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Accelerometer reference SS: " + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER))));
   }
}
```

When my smartphone had Lollipop, the output of the hashCodes were the same both in the Activity and in the Service. However, I updated my smartphone to Marshmallow and now the hashCode is different. The above outputs are now always like this:

*Accelerometer hashCode MA: 262356196*

*Accelerometer reference MA: fa33ce4*

*Accelerometer hashCode SS: 26510821*

*Accelerometer reference SS: 19485e5*

I can't figure out why a simple software update is making the hashCodes having a different behaviour, and I need them to have the same behaviour. Can you help me?

-- UPDATE --

**Why I want this?**

In my MainActivity I am "printing" in the view all the sensors that the smartphone has. This is done dynamically like this:

```
TextView sensorLayout = new TextView(this);
sensorLayout.setText(sensor.getStringType());
sensorLayout.setId(sensor.hashCode());
sensorLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

mainLayout.addView(sensorLayout);
```

Then, the SensorService is a listener. Everytime the *onSensorChanged()* is called I want to inform the main activity of this change so I can see the new values.
I do so by broadcasting an intent with two extras (a string with the new values and an integer with the hashCode of the sensor). The MainActivity needs to know which view it should change and it is done so like this:

```
int hashCode = intent.getIntExtra(SensorService.EXTRA_SENSOR_HASHCODE, 0);
TextView sensorLayout = (TextView) mainLayout.findViewById(hashCode);
sensorLayout.setText(intent.getStringExtra(SensorService.EXTRA_SENSOR_INFO));
```

Comment: "I need them to have the same behaviour" -- why? I would never assume that 2+ `Sensor` objects would have the same `hashCode()` value, even for the same type of sensor.

Comment: In my head I think that is reasonable to think that *getDefaultSensor()* should give a reference to the same sensor (in my code the accelerometer) wherever it is called. Indeed, it seem it was the behaviour in lollipop.

Comment: "In my head I think that is reasonable to think that getDefaultSensor() should give a reference to the same sensor" -- I am not aware of any documentation that would imply this behavior. AFAIK, you relied on side effects of an implementation, which was a risky move, and you are now paying the price. So, I'll ask again: **why** do you "need them to have the same behaviour"? If you explain **why** you relied upon this side effect, perhaps we can suggest workarounds for you.

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh, ok, I didn't understand you. I have updated my question with further explanations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.

In my specific case, I decided to do a simple solution:
As I needed the hash in the form of a integer, I used the `sensor.getType()` function instead of the `sensor.hashCode()` and my problem is now solved! As far as I saw in the documentation, this method returns a unique integer for each sensor that exists in a smartphone.

Answer (score 1):

The identity hashcode is always the default java.lang.Object implementation, even if the class for a particular object overrides this and computes a different hash code.

The identity hashcode takes no account of the content of the object, just where it is located. The ordinary hashcode may (should) take account of content. Thus, the identity hashcodes for two strings that each contain "hello world" would be different, but the ordinary hashcodes would be the same.

Comment: I think I understand that, however, I didn't have this issue when using Lollipop. Why? And how I could have the same behaviour now in android 6?

Comment: @tjiagoM That just means that object location was the same in Lollipop. Anyway, I think your desired implimentation is ordinary hashcode. It should be available in any class, derrieved from Object, so try mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)).hashCode()

Comment: But in my post I show that I am using hashCode() and it is giving different values...

Comment: @tjiagoM oh, sorry, I thaught that you only called IdentityHashCode. That could mean that HashCode method is poorly implemented and you can override it with you own - for example, use md5 hash from getType()+getVendor()+getVersion() - it should give you unique hashes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, probably that would work. However, it means that everytime the SensorService wants to send information to the MainActivity, it needs to compute a md5 hash. I think that it would be too computationally expensive.

Comment: @tjiagoM Ok, in that case you can use string concatenation (type+vendor+version) as a hash - there is no need for md5. Also, I suppose that phone has only one sensor of a type - for example, I doubt that there is a phone with two temperature sensors. If it is the case, you can use sensor type as a hash.

Answer (score 1):

> I do so by broadcasting an intent with two extras (a string with the new values and an integer with the hashCode of the sensor).

If by "broadcasting an intent", you mean that you are calling `sendBroadcast()` on a `Context`, please bear in mind that by default you are leaking private user data. Any app can listen to your broadcasts and get sensor data, even without having the appropriate permissions.

If by "broadcasting an intent", you mean that you are calling `sendBroadcast()` on `LocalBroadcastManager`, then I can see three likely approaches to solving your problem:

1. Replace that with an event bus (e.g., greenrobot's EventBus), so you can pass the `Sensor` object itself to the UI layer.
2. Use your own identifier instead of `hashCode()`, so both the service and the activity can agree on how to identify some particular sensor.
3. Get rid of the service, and have the activity register for sensor events itself.